# Combine an array with other arrays, push each combination Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I'm trying to take an array, and compare each value of that array to the next value in the array. When I run my code, components that should match with more than one array only return one match, instead of all of them. I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere, but for the life of my I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

This is my code:

**INPUT**

```
minterms = [["4",[0,1,0,0]],
           ["8",[1,0,0,0]],
           ["9",[1,0,0,1]],
           ["10",[1,0,1,0]],
           ["12",[1,1,0,0]],
           ["11",[1,0,1,1]],
           ["14",[1,1,1,0]],
           ["15",[1,1,1,1]]];
```

**Function**

```
function combineMinterms(minterms) {
var match = 0;
var count;
var loc;
var newMin = [];
var newMiny = [];
var used = new Array(minterms.length);

//First Component
for (x = 0; x < minterms.length; x++) {
if(minterms[x][1][minterms[x][1].length - 1] == "*") {
  newMin.push(minterms[x].slice());
  continue;
};
  //Second Component
  for (y = x + 1; y < minterms.length; y++) {
  count = 0;
    //Compare each value
    for (h = 0; h < minterms[x][1].length; h++) {
      if (minterms[x][1][h] != minterms[y][1][h]) {
      count++;
      loc = h;
      }
      if (count >= 2) {break; };
    }
    //If only one difference, push to new
    if (count === 1) {
      newMin.push(minterms[x].slice());
      newMiny = minterms[y].slice();
      newMin[match][1][loc] = "-";
      while(newMin[match][0].charAt(0) === 'd') {
        newMin[match][0] = newMin[match][0].substr(1);
      }
      while(newMiny[0].charAt(0) === 'd') {
        newMiny[0] = newMiny[0].substr(1);
      }
      newMin[match][0] += "," + newMiny[0];
      used[x] = 1;
      used[y] = 1;
      match++;
      continue;
    }
}
  //If never used, push to new
  if(used[x] != 1) {
    newMin.push(minterms[x].slice());
    newMin[match][1].push("*");
    match++;
  }
}
 return newMin; 
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
newMin = [["4,12",[-,1,0,0]],
         ["8,9",[1,0,0,-]],
         ["8,10",[1,0,-,0]],
         ["8,12",[1,-,0,0]],
         ["9,11",[1,0,-,1]],
         ["10,11",[1,0,1,-]],
         ["10,14",[1,-,1,0]],
         ["12,14",[1,1,-,0]],
         ["11,15",[1,-,1,1]],
         ["14,15",[1,1,1,-]]];
```

It will combine term 8, with 9 but won't continue to combine term 8 with 10, 12

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the desired output, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice` performs a shallow copy.

Each entry in `minterms` is an array of a string and a nested array.

When you slice the entry, you get a new array with a copy of the string and a copy of the Array object reference. But that copy of the Array reference still points to the array contained in an element of `minterms`.

When you update the nested array

```
newMin[match][1][loc] = "-";
```

you are updating the nested array within the input. I never fathomed the logic of what you are doing, but I believe this is the problem, with solution of cloning the nested array (as well) when cloning an input array element.

A secondary issue you will probably wish to fix is that not all variables were declared: `var x,y,h;` or equivalent inline declarations are missing.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I was trying to wrap my head around what was wrong forever.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let minterms = [4,8,9,10,12,11,14,15];
let newMin = [];

minterms.map((value, index) =>{
  minterms.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
      accumulator = value;
      let out = (accumulator ^ currentValue).toString(2);
     if(out.split('').filter(n=>n==="1").length == 1) newMin.push([value, currentValue]);
}, value);
});

console.log(newMin);
```

There is a better approach (in 10 lines of code). Since you're working with binary representations, you might want to consider using [BitWise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operators. When coupled with array operators it makes most of this straight forward.

For instance:

Given a match means only a single bit differs between two binary numbers:

The bitwise XOR operator returns 1 for each bit that doesn't match. So:

```
0100 XOR 1000 results in 1000
```

Now, we need to count the number of '1' digits in the binary number returned. We can use the length property of an array to do this. To turn 1000 into an array, first we turn the binary into a string:

The binary representation of the integer 4 is easily retrieved with:

```
num.toString(2)
```

So if num === 4, the output above is the string "0100".

Now we use `str.split()` to turn the string into an array. Remove everything from the array that is not a '1'. Now simply get the length property. If the length === 1, it is a match.

I put together a solution like this for you. It is close to your use case. I didn't use the funny dash style in the output because *that was not part of your question*.

https://jsbin.com/xezuwax/edit?js,console